# Can't evaluate original Y combinator, two other variants do work, what do I miss?

Tags: combinatorics, lambda-calculus

I have made an evaluator of Lambda expressions. I tried to do Y combinator, but for some reason I can't get the original one working:

$$λf.(λx.f \space (x \space x)) \space (λx.f \space (x \space x))\tag1$$

This is probably for a reason, I don't know how to interpret $f (x \space x)$ part, or my evaluator does it right-wise or  call-by-value.

However these two variants of the Y combinator do work as expected:

$$λf.((λx.(f \space (y.((x \space x) \space y)))) \space (λx.(f \space (y.((x \space x) \space y))))) \tag2$$

and

$$λf.((λx.(x \space x)) \space (λx.(f \space (λy.((x \space x) y)))))\tag3$$

Latter is evidently a self-application version of the former one.

---

Already, I have found that most implementations use the latter two equations:

**Javascript**

http://kestas.kuliukas.com/YCombinatorExplained/

**Python**

https://github.com/bzanchet/pycombinator/blob/master/pycombinator.py#L194

**Scheme**

https://github.com/calincru/Y-Combinator#the-strict-applicative-order-y-combinator

---

I have added parentheses for the last two expression to make it clear the order of the evaluation. For the first case, I'm not totally sure, but when I interpret it like this:

$$λf.((λx.(f \space (x \space x))) \space (λx.(f \space (x \space x))))\tag4$$

it will cause infinite loop. Also self-application version of it would simply be:

$$λf.((λx.(x \space x)) \space (λx.(f \space (x \space x))))\tag5$$

Right?

I have used my own macro run on [Hy](http://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/index.html) language interpreter, so I rather discuss about the abstract implementation side of the problem than specific code. But this is how I'm applying Y combinator to the standard factorial function:

$$
((( f · (( x · (f \space (x \space x))) \space ( x · (f \space (x \space x)))))\\
  ( f · ( n · (if \space (= \space n \space 1) \space 1 \space (* \space n \space (f \space (dec \space n)))))))\\
  7)\tag6
$$

Result should be: 5040.

Note: In Hy, prefix notation of the mathematical operations are used.

Comment: What's the problem with the original one? Does your evaluiator crash (in which case this would be a coding issue, off-topic here), loop infinitely, give the wrong result...? What expression are you evaluating? We can help you understand why a particular term evaluates in a particular way, but we can't guess what your program is doing.

Comment: About the parentheses: parentheses have no effect on the order of evaluation. They only affect how the term is parsed. If you aren't sure about that, I recommend that you draw a syntax diagram ($\lambda x.M$ is a tree with $\lambda$ at the root, $x$ as the left child and $M$ as the right child, etc.). Order of evaluation is about which path the evaluator takes through the tree to find something to evaluate.

Comment: I think main problem is that I cannot decide what part is function and what argument at each part in the first expression. No crash, no infinite loop. If i provide factorial function to the first y combinator, either some sort of function or alternatively int error is returned. I will provide more information tomorrow.

Comment: I added more information. Hope it helps to see what I'm after.

Comment: It sounds to me like a problem with your your implementation of lambda calculus, i.e., the problem you're describing seems to be just a *parsing error*. How did you implement your language? I'll show you mine and you show me yours. Here's mine: http://plzoo.andrej.com/language/lambda.html

Comment: @andrej-bayer that was nice. Mine is just a very short code built upon Hy language. Macro simply transforms lambda expression to function and passes variables to it, if provided: https://gist.github.com/markomanninen/f2e3637f285112f87845cd5863197e10

Anyway, I got few good ideas from your implementation and did something more verbose recently. Getting closer of the idea of evaluating lambda expressions lazy way, but not yet there. Good to have options for eager and deep evaluation strategies.